# Routing within react throws "No duplicate props allowed "

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

All my routing is done within my app.js. However within my routes I receive multiple errors for the same thing.I am not passing props through this section of my application so I am unsure why I receive this.

The error I receive

```
[1] ./src/App.js
[1]   Line 70:36:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 71:31:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 72:39:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 73:44:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 78:11:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 85:11:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 91:11:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 94:42:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 95:39:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 99:11:   No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 103:47:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 104:47:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 108:11:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 114:11:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 120:11:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 126:11:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 132:11:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[1]   Line 138:11:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
```

The routing section of my app.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/reset" exact component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route exact path="/Register" exact component={RegisterPage} />
        <Route exact path="/confirm-email" exact component={ConfirmEmail} />

        <RegisterAuthRoute
          exact
          path="/confirm-register"
          exact
          component={ConfirmRegisterPage}
        />

        <ResetAuthRoute
          exact
          path="/confirm-Password"
          exact
          component={ConfirmPassword}
        />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/profile-update-account-details"
          exact
          component={UpdateAccountDetailsPage}
        />
        <AuthRoute exact path="/profile" exact component={ProfilePage} />
        <AuthRoute exact path="/home" exact component={Home} />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/user-questions"
          exact
          component={UserQuestions}
        />

        <AuthRoute exact path="/user-history" exact component={History} />
        <AuthRoute exact path="/admin-center" exact component={AdminCenter} />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/admin-question-editor"
          exact
          component={AdminQuestionEditor}
        />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/admin-view-users"
          exact
          component={AdminViewUsers}
        />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/admin-view-users-severity-high"
          exact
          component={AdminViewUsersSeverityHigh}
        />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/admin-view-users-severity-medium"
          exact
          component={AdminViewUsersSeverityMedium}
        />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/admin-view-users-severity-completed"
          exact
          component={AdminViewUsersSeverityCompleted}
        />
        <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/admin-view-users"
          exact
          component={AdminViewUsers}
        />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Essentially the question is. Why am I receiving this error ? How is this error resolved?

Comment: add your App.js full code

Comment: property exact is dublicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're passing the `exact` prop twice to each route.

See [react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) on exact.

Comment: Ahh okay. Should this just be passed for route and not component then ?

Comment: `exact` is in relation to the element e.g. `AuthRoute` rather than in relation to the other props e.g. `path` and `component` so therefore it only needs to appear once per element.